# Google Earth KML - href fragment URL getting cut off at the # - won't open in browser

Tags: url, href, kml, google-earth

I have a KML file that includes a list of placemarks.  In the placemark description I have links that point to a webpage I want users to open in a browser.  The href points to a fragment URL, meaning it has a '#' as a delimiter, followed by a parameter related to the placemark.  When I view the placemark balloon I see the clickable link, but when I click it sends the URL to the browser cutting off the '#' and the parameter that follows.  However if I right-click on the link, copy link location, and paste it into a browser it works fine...I'd like to avoid those few extra steps though.

The link looks like this:  mywebsite/directory#12345678
but it opens in the browser like this: mywebsite/directory
which doesn't work.

From some searching around I see the # is used to enable fly to features (see below).  Is there a workaround or fix so that I can make google earth send the complete fragment URL to the browser, without cutting off the # and parameter?

--from Google Earth deveopers group

Other Behavior Specified Through Use of the  Element
KML supports the use of two attributes within the  element: href and type.

The anchor element  contains an href attribute that specifies a URL.

If the href is a KML file and has a .kml or .kmz file extension, Google Earth loads that file directly when the user clicks it. If the URL ends with an extension not known to Google Earth (for example, .html), the URL is sent to the browser.

The href can be a fragment URL (that is, a URL with a # sign followed by a KML identifier). When the user clicks a link that includes a fragment URL, by default the browser flies to the Feature whose ID matches the fragment. If the Feature has a LookAt or Camera element, the Feature is viewed from the specified viewpoint.

The behavior can be further specified by appending one of the following three strings to the fragment URL:

•;flyto (default) - fly to the Feature
•;balloon - open the Feature's balloon but do not fly to the Feature 
•;balloonFlyto - open the Feature's balloon and fly to the Feature

I'd greatly appreciate any ideas, suggestions, or workarounds!

Comment: A snippet of the KML in question would help provide the context.

Answer (score 0):

If the target URL "mywebsite/directory" results in an HTML document with a target id defined with appropriate anchor (e.g. 1234578) then it normally can be accessed via clicking a link via KML from Google Earth.

There may be an issue with how the URL is escaped in the KML. Wrapping HTML in the feature description via CDATA block sometimes helps.

Here's where having a '#' in the URL for a link in KML works as you'd expect.

KML

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
<Placemark>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
        Visiting a linked resource.
        See <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1">reference</a>
        ]]>
    </description>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Target HTML links.html

```
<html>
...
<h3><a name="h-12.1.1">12.1.1</a> Visiting a linked resource</h3>
...
</html>
```

The behavior might be different whether the web browser is configured as external or internal to Google Earth. In Tools/Options/General menu check/uncheck the option "*Show web results in external browser*" to see if the action changes.